# Using OpenStreetMap data in QGIS, but street names repeat too much

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have downloaded some roads in a section of Los Angeles from OpenStreetMap. I used overpassturbo.eu to generate the data, using the expression highway=primary. However, because these streets are broken into many segments (bridges, changes in speed limits, etc.), the street names repeat too much. Is there a way in QGIS, or elsewhere, to edit this data to remove some of these repeating street names? I have been looking for something in QGIS, but so far no luck.

Comment: You can space labels further apart with placement and distance http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html

Answer (score 1):

You can "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in the Maplex extension of ArcGIS, in any version between 9.3 and 10.5.  Newer version of ArcGIS for Desktop include Maplex, so you will not have to buy it separately as in the past.  You will have to turn on Maplex in the Labeling toolbar before this will work.

You can set a certain radius for labels not to repeat:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/removing-duplicate-labels-within-a-given-radius.htm

The Label Density tab within Label Manager is probably the place to start.

You can also do this without Maplex using the standard label engine, but you will have less control over label placement:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/prioritizing-and-positioning-labels-working-with-d.htm

Comment: This question was about QGIS, not ArcGIS.